# Wordpress register_sidebar function failing

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, themes

So I have created 3 custom widget zones for my themes footer. the show in the admin panel and also show front-end. However, it would appear the IF statement is failing on me but I am unable to see why. So there is content there if no available widgets have been dragged in but should change when you drop one in.

Here is the functions.php file:

```
function create_widget( $name, $id, $description ) {
    $args = array(
        'name'          => __( $name ),
        'id'            => $id,
        'description'   => $description,
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h5>',
        'after_title'   => '</h5>' 
        );

    register_sidebar( $args );
}

create_widget( 'Left Footer', 'footer_left', 'Displays in the bottom left of footer' );
create_widget( 'Middle Footer','footer_middle', 'Displays in the middle of footer' );
create_widget( 'Right Footer', 'footer_right', 'Displays in the bottom right of footer' );
```

Here is footer.php which displays the widget areas front-end (or should do at least)

```
<div class="grid_4 footer-left">
                <?php if( dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-left' ) ): ?>
                <?php else: ?>

                    <h5>Twitter</h5>
                    <p>Install the TwiGet plugin and place the widget here in the left bottom footer</p>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>


            <div class="grid_4 footer-middle">
                <?php if( dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-middle' ) ): ?>
                <?php else: ?>

                    <h5>dribbble</h5>
                    <p>Install the dribbble plugin and place the widget here in the left bottom footer</p>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="grid_4 omega footer-right">
                <?php if( dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-right' ) ): ?>
                <?php else: ?>

                    <h5>Treehouse</h5>
                    <p>Install the treehouse plugin and place the widget here in the left bottom footer</p>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

I am really struggling to see where problem is here? I have checked for typos and anything that would look to be incorrect but still nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in the sidebar ids. you register the ids with underscore `footer_left` and you try to get them with hyphen `footer-left`